# button error viewflipper android

Tags: java, android, viewflipper

i`m trying to do android viewflipper. i have 3 views i would to be changed on button click (next & previous). i wrote these code and the log said there is button widget error. How to solve this?

my xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/radial_background">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_buy1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buy_previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"> 
   </Button> 


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buy_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buy_previous"> 
    </Button>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/buy_submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buy_next"> 
     </Button>  

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/relative_buy1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <ViewFlipper 
        android:id="@+id/ViewFlipper01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buy_item_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/buy_item_name_et"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/buy_item_name">
            </EditText>         

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buy_ques_category"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            </TextView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buy_food_cat_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/buy_ques_category"> 
            </Button>    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buy_education_cat_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/buy_food_cat_button"> 
            </Button>   
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buy_personal_cat_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/buy_education_cat_button">   
            </Button>   

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/buy_ques_cost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
            </TextView>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/buy_ques_cost_et"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/buy_ques_cost">
            </EditText>      

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

my activity

```
package apps.questions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
import apps.project.R;

public class BuyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

ViewFlipper vf;

private static final String FOOD = "Food/Drinks";
private static final String EDUCATION = "Education";
private static final String PERSONAL = "Personal";

Button food_cat;
Button education_cat;
Button personal_cat;
Button next;
Button previous;
Button submit;

TextView item_name;
TextView item_cost;
TextView item_cat;
EditText name;
EditText cost;

ContentValues cv;
String iName;
double iPrice;
String iCategory;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buy_advice_layout);


    inflateView();

    /*food_cat.setOnClickListener(this);
    education_cat.setOnClickListener(this);
    personal_cat.setOnClickListener(this);*/
}

public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}

private void inflateView() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    cv = new ContentValues();
    vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);

    next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_next);
    previous = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_previous);
    submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_submit);

    /*food_cat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_food_cat_button);
    education_cat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_education_cat_button);
    personal_cat = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_personal_cat_button);*/

    item_name = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.buy_item_name);
    item_name.setText("Please enter the name of the item you wish to buy");
    item_cat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.buy_ques_category);
    item_cat.setText("Please select the category of the item you wish to buy by clicking on the category button");
    item_cost = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.buy_ques_cost);
    item_cost.setText("Please enter the price of the item you wish to buy");
    name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.buy_item_name_et);
    cost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.buy_ques_cost_et);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v == next) {

        vf.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.push_left_in));
        vf.showNext();
    }

    if (v == previous) {

        vf.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(v.getContext(), R.anim.push_left_out));
        vf.showPrevious();
    }

    if (v == submit) {
        //vf.showPrevious();
    }

    if (v == food_cat) {
        iCategory = FOOD;
    }

    if (v == education_cat) {
        iCategory = EDUCATION;
    }

    if (v == personal_cat) {
        iCategory = PERSONAL;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If you want help, add the error message and preferably the stacktrace. From your questions it is not clear 1) What the error is. 2) What the error does. Does your app crash? Are you able to compile your code? Etc. etc.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the assignment of your click listeners to your buttons. Use the following code just below your find view by id calls for the buttons.

```
        next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_next);
        previous = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_previous);
        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buy_submit);

        //New code
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        previous.setOnClickListener(this);
        submit.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: oh my, i didnt realized it. tyvm sir